# Excel Extract Numbers From Text String And Sum Them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help.I have this:

A1: 6-2, 6-2

A2: 8-1, 4-3

A3: 6-2, 6-3,5-3

And I want to sum all the numbers before the "-".

Example: In B1 i want to have 12 (6+6) from A1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will do it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),FIND("-",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1)&"-")-1)*999+1,999)))-1))
```

[image]